# How can I put images together in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make something like this in Bootstrap or CSS3 (responsive):

[image]

You can find this at www.apple.com

Check this please: http://www.bootply.com/8O3HNWvgoL
As you see, the images have small gap. I want them to sit tight together, but I do not know how.

Comment: Like what? An image carousel? You could always start by doing some research and finding something that does it already or attempting it yourself. Don't be lazy and expect other people to give you a complete written solution for free

Comment: The images below the carousel.
I've been trying to do this with the Bootstrap grid system (cols and rows), but it go so well, and I am currently stuck.

Comment: You need to post the code in your attempt in your question in that case, preferably accompanied by a link to JSFiddle or Bootply

Comment: Thanks, will do! It's my first time, and I am sorry if I did anything wrong :-)

Comment: Post your code here along with a link to [bootply](http://www.bootply.com)(similar to jsfiddle but includes bootstrap).

Comment: @ManolisC. http://www.bootply.com/8O3HNWvgoL
As you see, the images have small gap. I want them to sit tight together, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `col-sm-3` to archive this.I used Grid system to make 4 columns.

So, here is the full code.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3"> <img src="https://www.apple.com/home/images/promo_yosemite.jpg" width="364" height="200" alt="OS X Yosemite. Every bit as powerful as it looks."> </div>
<div class="col-sm-3"> <img src="https://www.apple.com/home/images/promo_dreams.jpg" width="364" height="200" alt="You’re more powerful than you think. iPhone 5s."> </div>
<div class="col-sm-3"> <img class="wide" src="https://www.apple.com/home/images/promo_college_reminder.jpg" width="364" height="200" alt="Buy a Mac, iPad, or iPhone for college by Sept. 9 and get a gift card.*"> </div>
<div class="col-sm-3"> <img src="https://www.apple.com/home/images/promo_diversity.jpg" width="364" height="200" alt="Inclusion inspires innovation. Tim Cook on diversity at Apple."></div>
</div>
```

## WORKING DEMO

http://www.bootply.com/wbweldHuxT

## UPDATED DEMO

http://www.bootply.com/U53RJi6Gci

To remove gaps between images add `.col-md-4 {padding: 0;}` to Css file! OR inline style to apply this only to this section.

In-line Style example

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="padding:0;"> IMAGE </div>
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, check: http://www.bootply.com/8O3HNWvgoL
As you see, the images have small gap. I want them to sit tight together, but I do not know how.

Comment: Add `.col-md-4 {
   padding: 0; 
  }` to css ALSO: See updated demo!

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!
I tried it first, but it didn't change. But once I added "!important" to the tag, it worked.

THANK YOU!

Comment: You should use inline style without !important. It will also override css in file. Glad to know it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the grid system, this is pretty simple to do. [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/GH9cBuRnyC)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100%"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100%"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100%"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
          <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100%"/>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note - If you want these to stack in mobile, you can use `col-sm-3` instead, or in mobile AND tablet you can use `col-md-3` and so on.

EDIT: To eliminate the "gap" between images, you have to remove the padding Bootstrap has on col-xx-xx classes. [Updated Demo](http://www.bootply.com/e4D6JWElv2)

```
.col-xs-3 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried exactly like that, but if you check here: http://puu.sh/b8S45/00bbb01b6a.png , you can see that the images have a small gap between each picture. I want them to sit tight together

Comment: To achieve that you need to add one small bit of CSS to remove Bootstrap's padding on `col-**-*`: `.col-xs-3 { padding: 0; }` - http://www.bootply.com/e4D6JWElv2

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the grid system.

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="yourimage.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="yourimage.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="yourimage.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use .col-md-1,.col-md-4,.col-md-6 and .col-md8(remember, the total grid should be 12).You can uso too .col-xs-(Phones (<768px),.col-sm-(≥768px) and .col-lg-(≥1200px).

to remove the space between the images

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 removeSpace">
        <img src="yourimage.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 removeSpace">
        <img src="yourimage.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 removeSpace">
        <img src="yourimage.png" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.removeSpace {
     padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, check: http://www.bootply.com/8O3HNWvgoL
As you see, the images have small gap. I want them to sit tight together, but I do not know how.

Comment: @SuperizeeInc i've modified my code, let's try again